# What is the referent point here in this sentence?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, syntax

> Still, I should advise you by all means to go and visit Menelaus, who has lately come off a voyage among such distant peoples as no man could ever hope to get back from, **when the winds had once carried him so far out of his reckoning**; even birds cannot fly the distance in a twelvemonth, so vast and terrible are the seas that they must cross. ([source: Homer's *Odyssey*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Bmploq6ZS-UC&lpg=PA23&dq=all%20means%20to%20go%20and%20visit%20Menelaus&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=all%20means%20to%20go%20and%20visit%20Menelaus&f=false))

Is this "him" talking about "no man"?
And what is the time referent that causes the past perfect tense to be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *when* clause modifies the *no man could ever hope* clause; the two comprise a *when* conditional. The *when* clause is cast in with a past-form perfect *had carried* because its head, the *hope* clause, employs a past-form *could* - they are both imaginary irrealis pasts. Compare the Rieu translation:

> ... he has only just got back from abroad, and from a region so remote that one **might** well give up all hope of return once the winds **had** blown one astray into that wide expanse of sea, which is so vast ...